# Differential Equation-Separation of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

1) Solve the following differential equation by separation of variables (or otherwise) $$\frac{dy}{dx}-1=e^{x-y}$$.

***What I tried***:-
Suppose $$z^2=e^{x-y}$$
        $$\Rightarrow 2z\frac{dz}{dx}=e^{x-y}(1-\frac{dy}{dx})$$
$$\Rightarrow 2z\frac{dz}{dx}=z^2(1-\frac{dy}{dx})$$
$$\Rightarrow 2\frac{dz}{dx}=z(1-\frac{dy}{dx})$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=1-\frac{2dz}{zdx} \tag1$$

Again, $$\frac{dy}{dx}-1=e^{x-y}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=1+z^2 \tag2$$

Equating $(1)$ and $(2)$,

$$1+z^2=1-\frac{2dz}{zdx}$$
$$\Rightarrow z^3dx=-2dz$$
$$\Rightarrow z^{-3}dz=-\frac{1}{2}dx$$
$$\Rightarrow \int z^{-3}dz=\int -\frac{1}{2}dx$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{z^{-2}}{-2}=-\frac{1}{2} x+\frac{c}{2}$$
$$\Rightarrow -z^{-2}=-x+c$$
$$\Rightarrow z^{-2}-x+c=0$$

Am I correct ?

Comment: **Hint:** Try letting $$v = y - x \implies v' = y' - x'$$ Substitute those and then you get a Separable Equation.

Comment: @Moo I was doing same thing moo

Comment: With everyone telling you other ways of solving the problem, it may not be clear: the answer to your actual question is "yes". What you did is correct. It may not be the simplest approach possible, but there is nothing wrong with it (other than not translating back into $x$ and $y$ instead of the variable $z$ that you introduced).

Comment: @paul did you downvote everyone? Actually you are right that noone checked his work.

Comment: @KingTut - no, I didn't downvote. You didn't answer the exact question asked, but you and the others satisfied the actual need. I just thought it would be good to point out that the work in the question was actually correct.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thats why i said you are right and you did good work! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets try $x-y = t$ and $t_x = 1-y_x$

$$-\frac{dt}{dx} = e^t \\ 
\int -e^{-t} dt = \int dx\\
e^{-t} = x+c$$

Answer (score 1):

If you put $z=x-y$ then you can find easily the solution of the problem.
By putting $z=x-y$ the above ODE becomes $$-\frac{dz}{dx}=e^z.$$
By separation of variable, $$-e^{-z}dz=dx.$$
By integrating we get $$e^{y-x}=x+c.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$y'-1=e^{x-y} \implies (y'-1)e^{y-x}=1 $$
Integrate simply since on the left side you have a derivative
$$\int e^{y-x}(y'-1)dx=x+K \implies \int (e^{y-x})'dx=x+K$$
$$e^{y-x}=x+K$$
***Another way***

substitute $y=\ln(z)$:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}-1=e^{x-y}$$
$$\frac{z'}{z}-1=\frac {e^{x}}z$$
$${z'}-z= {e^{x}}$$
$$({ze^{-x}})'=1$$
$$z=e^{x}(x+K)$$
$$e^y=e^{x}(x+K)$$
$$\boxed{y=x+\ln|x+K|}$$

Comment: Quite a nice observation!

Comment: Thank you @KingTut.....